# How to find the vocabulary size of a spaCy model?

Tags: nlp, documentation, spacy, vocabulary

I am trying to find the vocabulary size of the large English model, i.e. `en_core_web_lg`, and I find three different sources of information:

- spaCy's docs: 685k keys, 685k unique vectors
- `nlp.vocab.__len__()`: 1340242 # (number of lexemes)
- `len(vocab.strings)`: 1476045

What is the difference between the three? I have not been able to find the answer in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most useful numbers are the ones related to word vectors. `nlp.vocab.vectors.n_keys` tells you how many tokens have word vectors and `len(nlp.vocab.vectors)` tells you how many unique word vectors there are (multiple tokens can refer to the same word vector in `md` models).

`len(vocab)` is the number of cached lexemes. In `md` and `lg` models most of those `1340242` lexemes have some precalculated features (like `Token.prob`) but there can be additional lexemes in this cache without precalculated features since more entries can be added as you process texts.

`len(vocab.strings)` is the number of strings related to both tokens and annotations (like `nsubj` or `NOUN`), so it's not a particularly useful number. All strings used anywhere in training or processing are stored here so that the internal integer hashes can be converted back to strings when needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is there a way to determine which strings have a distinct word vector, and which map to the same vector? What is the default string/word vector that all out-of-vocabulary words map to?

Comment: Check out `Vectors.data` and `Vectors.key2row`: https://spacy.io/api/vectors#attributes. The default OOV is all 0s.

Answer (score 1):

Since spaCy 2.3+, according to the [release notes](https://spacy.io/usage/v2-3), the lexemes are not loaded in `nlp.vocab`; so using `len(nlp.vocab)` is not effective. Instead, use `nlp.meta['vectors']` to find the number of unique vectors and words. Here is the relevant section from release notes:

> To reduce the initial loading time, the lexemes in `nlp.vocab` are no
> longer loaded on initialization for models with vectors. As you
> process texts, the lexemes will be added to the vocab automatically,
> just as in small models without vectors.
>
> To see the number of unique vectors and number of words with vectors,
> see `nlp.meta['vectors']`, for example for `en_core_web_md` there are
> 20000 unique vectors and 684830 words with vectors:
>
> ```
> {
>     'width': 300,
>     'vectors': 20000,
>     'keys': 684830,
>     'name': 'en_core_web_md.vectors'
> }
> ```